# Troubleshoot failed cron not sending emails

Tags: cron

Here is the server info from `lsb_release -a`

[image]

In our crontab, below the comments and above the cron commands we have `MAILTO=myemail@gmail.com`, however no emails are being sent to myemail@gmail.com. I'm not sure if the server has sendgrid or any other emailing tools installed, or if they are needed. Our cron logs all currently get sent to a file at `/var/mail/myusername`, and I can hop in and see them with `vim /var/mail/myusername`. How can I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `mailx` or install the package. If you need them to go to Google, then you need to install and configure a mta package such as postfix or exim. You also have a high enough rating to know that you do not post images where plain text will do.